# LabelPlacement in high zoom and AnchorPoint

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld

In the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html) of geoserver I found, that

```
<AnchorPoint>
  <AnchorPointX>
    0
  </AnchorPointX>
  <AnchorPointY>
    0.5
  </AnchorPointY>
</AnchorPoint>
```

should set the label to the right of the anchor point.

[image]

Most of the time this works for me.

But not for hight zoom levels.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is my SLD

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1.0" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>Beschriftung Druckleitung (DL)</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Name>Beschriftung Druckleitung (DL)</Name>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>Single symbol (gross)</Name>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>533</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                                <Fill>
                                    <SvgParameter name="fill">#b79087</SvgParameter>
                                </Fill>
                                <Stroke>
                                    <SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</SvgParameter>
                                    <SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</SvgParameter>
                                </Stroke>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>2</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>Single symbol (mittel)</Name>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>533</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>34085</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                                <Fill>
                                    <SvgParameter name="fill">#b79087</SvgParameter>
                                </Fill>
                                <Stroke>
                                    <SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</SvgParameter>
                                    <SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</SvgParameter>
                                </Stroke>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>1</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>Single symbol (klein)</Name>
                    <MinScaleDenominator>34085</MinScaleDenominator>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <TextSymbolizer>
                        <Label>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>label_text</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </Label>
                        <Font>
                            <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-style">normal</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="font-weight">normal</CssParameter>
                            <SvgParameter name="font-size">
                                <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
                                    <ogc:Function name="env">
                                        <ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal>
                                    </ogc:Function>
                                    <ogc:Literal>17</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>133</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>266</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>15</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>533</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>14</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>1065</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>13</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>2130</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>4261</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>11</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>8521</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>9</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>17043</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>34085</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>68171</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>136342</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>272683</ogc:Literal>
                                    <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>
                            </SvgParameter>
                        </Font>
                        <LabelPlacement>
                            <PointPlacement>
                                <AnchorPoint>
                                    <AnchorPointX>0</AnchorPointX>
                                    <AnchorPointY>0.5</AnchorPointY>
                                </AnchorPoint>
                            </PointPlacement>
                        </LabelPlacement>
                        <Fill>
                            <SvgParameter name="fill">#8b0000</SvgParameter>
                        </Fill>
                        <VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>                    
                    </TextSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Can someone explain to me why the text is not always exactly in the middle right of the dot?

Comment: probably because you are changing the font size which changes the label size. and also because you change the symbol size

Comment: I understood that the text should always be displayed exactly vertical centered at the insertion point - regardless of the font size - if I set Y=0.5 and X=0 for the AnchorPoint.

Is not that right?

Comment: but the middle of the font may change with size, and the centre of the symbol may well change too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is caused by changing the size of the symbol and the size of the label font.

From my brief experiments where the centre line of the label is depends on if the font size is odd or even. This effect is mostly rounding error, and is especially noticeable when you are zoomed in to scales of 1:2 so individual pixels are huge.

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank you Ian. That convinces me. The problem occurs only in this small scales. The rounding is certainly the explanation.